Probability of a succession of events
[This is my first question on this site, I hope it is in-scope, if not please pardon me. I also don't know enough to tag this well]
I have no background in statistics and am hoping someone can help me find the answer to the following problem.
Imagine an event has a probability of success of 98%, and this event repeats X times (say 300) with each event being independent of the previous ones. What is the probability that more than 99% of these X events succeed? Ideally, each number in the problem (98%, 300, 99%) would be a variable that can be changed.

Let Y be the number of success events in n trials (pardon me for changing your notation). Then Y follows a binomial distribution (n=300, p=0.98). Now you're asking what's the probability of Y larger than n*0.99, one line of R command will give the answer:
pbinom(q=300*0.99, size=300, prob=0.98, lower.tail=F)

Very impressive (for a newbie like me), thanks a lot
